# How can a power converter small signal model predict transient behaviour during a load step which is a large signal disturbance?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, control, transfer-function, modeling

I [see](https://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/slua847/slua847.pdf?ts=1708667072168&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) small signal model being used to predict the Overshoot/Undershoot of output voltage due to a load step.

[image]

How do we justify this approach, since the [basic](https://www.coursera.org/learn/converter-control/lecture/YePQI/sect-7-2-5-perturbation-and-linearization) assumption of small signal modelling is the disturbance is small wrt DC values?
[image]

During the load step,$\Delta$ Iout would typically be large.

Comment: All these equations are linear or small-signal equations. They assume the converter's model remains linear in this mode - no op-amp saturation, slew-rate issues and so on - and the input or output steps are small enough in amplitude. As long as you see expression in the \$s\$-domain or people use Thévenin, Norton etc. it implies a linear circuit. Keep in mind that most expressions describing the behavior of a switching converters are approximate expressions which only hold within narrow conditions, a small variation around the bias point being one them.